# DataGridView Different cell formatting in same column possible?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, formatting

Again need help from this awsome comunity.

I have a WinForms app with DataGridView to display some data. 
There are especcialy two columns that are important to me. One is "Unit" and the second one is "Value". Unit has strings inside format and Value has numeric values. I would like to format the Value in each DataGridViewRow depending on what the Unit is. For example: if unit is 'piece', I need Value to be int (no decimal places). If unit is 'mm', I need to divide Value with 1000 and show two (2) decimal places and also change Unit to 'm'... Hope you understand. Also some graphic interpretation:

```
Unit   Value    ----> Wanted display format ----> Unit   Value
piece  100,00                                     piece   100
mm     10000,00                                   m       10,00
g      100000,00                                  kg      100,00
```

What would be the right way to aproach this?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's possible by setting the cell's style. You'll have to add a method to valuechanged event handler, that'd change it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx 
`DefaultCellStyle.Format` is what you need (the 'default' in the name can be misguiding)

Comment: Try this link as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You will need to handle the `CellFormatting()` event. In here, you can get access to the current row and column.

In this event you have access to the following properties in the `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs` type:

```
Public property CellStyle
Public property ColumnIndex
Public property DesiredType
Public property FormattingApplied   
Public property RowIndex    
Public property Value
```

Thus you can use the `RowIndex` property to look up the value in your `datasource` to get the other columns value for your conditional formatting.

I haven't got VS handy at the moment but something like:

```
private void OnCellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ColumnIndex == ValueColIndex)
  {
    string unit = datasource.Rows[e.RowIndex][ValueColIndex].ToString();
    switch(unit)
    {
      case "piece": e.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value).ToString();
       e.FormattingApplied = true;
       break;
      case "mm": e.Value = string.Format("{0:00}", Convert.ToDouble(e.Value) / 1000);
       e.FormattingApplied = true;
       break;
      //etc
    }
  }
}
```

PS, you may need to handle any exceptions in there.

Comment: Is it possible to get a simple example? :) Haven't used that event yet, so I don't know the right syntaxes... Will check the links provided in comments, but still would appritiate some code snippets.

Comment: just a quick question...what is "datasource"? the datatable I use as a datasource?

Comment: Correct. The DataTable or List<T> your grid is bound to