# DataGridView properties not being set when called from Form Load

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm having a really strange issue with the DataGridView control in a VS2008 / .NET 3.5 winforms project. I have a simple form with a grid. In the form constructor I call a function to bind the grind to a DataTable, and then loop through the rows setting the background colour of the last cell to LightGrey and the cell itself to read-only if the column value is true. After the form finishes loading the code didn't work i.e. the cells are not set to LightGrey and are not read-only (even though when I step through the code I can see the properties being set). I then call the function again from a button, but this time the colour is changed to LightGrey and the cell is made read-only i.e. the code works.

**CODE:**

```
 Dim dgr As DataGridViewRow  
 For i_DsRow As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            dr = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i_DsRow)

            For i_row As Integer = 0 To DgSearch.Rows.Count - 1
                dgr = DgSearch.Rows(i_row)

                If dr("DsColoumn1").ToString.ToUpper = dgr.Cells("DgColoumn1").Value.ToString.ToUpper Then
                    If Val(dr("Coloumn2").ToString) = 3 Then 
                        dgr.Cells("SomeColomname").Value = dr("SomeColoumName2").ToString
                        If dgr.Cells("SomeColomname3").Value.ToString <> "" Then dgr.Cells("SomeColomname3").Value &= ", "
                        dgr.Cells("SomeColomname3").Value &= dr("SomeColoumName2").ToString

                        SetCellColor(dgr.Cells("SomeColomname"), dgr.Cells("SomeColomname3"))
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

---

```
Private Sub SetCellColor(ByVal resultCell As DataGridViewCell, ByVal ColorCell As DataGridViewCell)
    If resultCell.Value.ToString().ToUpper = "A".ToUpper Or resultCell.Value.ToString().ToUpper = "B".ToUpper Then
        ColorCell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromName("Red")
    ElseIf resultCell.Value.ToString().ToUpper = "C".ToUpper Or resultCell.Value.ToString().ToUpper = "D".ToUpper Then
        ColorCell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromName("MediumSeaGreen")
    Else
        ColorCell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromName("Yellow")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: can we see some code please? Also, setting background colors should be done in a dedicated method like the cell_formatting for example

Comment: If resultCell.Value.ToString().ToUpper = "A".ToUpper Or resultCell.Value.ToString().ToUpper = "B".ToUpper Then
            ColorCell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromName("Red")
        ElseIf resultCell.Value.ToString().ToUpper = "C".ToUpper Or resultCell.Value.ToString().ToUpper = "D".ToUpper Then
            ColorCell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromName("MediumSeaGreen")
        Else
            ColorCell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromName("Yellow")
   End If

Comment: is this code in the form load?

Comment: I have fillgrid function which is calling on page load and after filling grid with data reader. I am using this code in for loop

Comment: So there are some variables there which we have no idea where they come from, such as ColorCell, resultCell. How are those guys passed in? Can we have the full routine?

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, can we see the for loop too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding the code. I would suggest putting all formatting in the [CellFormatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of the DataGridView.

There are a couple of gotchas that you have to watch, which looking at your code shouldn't be a problem but to be aware of:

1. This runs for each cell in the grid. Therefore Database lookups are a **really** bad idea.
2. You do best to get values where possible from the eventargs parameter of the method

If you need a code sample, I believe there are some good c# examples (possibly vb to) [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044075/datagridview-different-cell-formatting-in-same-column-possible) for example.